# Do ToolStripMenuItem have any underlying unmanaged resource?

Tags: c#, unmanagedresources, toolstripitem

I use `ToolStripMenuItem` inside some of my projects and allocate it using C# operator `new`:

```
ToolStripMenuItem someMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Some Item");
```

I read MSDN documentation on `IDisposable` interface and `using` statement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). It is still unclear for me if ToolStripMenuItem have any underlying unmanaged resource or not.

More precisely, should I take care of call to `Dispose(false)` method if some exception occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToolStripMenuItems inherit from Component, which does implement the IDisposable interface.

Using the `using()` syntax for a ToolStripMenuItem wouldn't really work since you generally want the menu item to exist for the end user to interact with it, and the `using()` syntax would immediately dispose of it.

It's unclear to me what "some exception occurs" has to do with the disposal of the ToolStrip item.  You shouldn't have to worry about disposing of it since it will be garbage collected when the hosted form gets closed.

Keep in mind though, that removing a ToolStripMenuItem from an items collection does not dispose of it, and in that case, you would want to call the dispose method yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Regarding exception I mean the problem described [here](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/404.html). As far as I understand from C# sample if some function after `ToolStripMenuItem` allocation causes an exception, the object goes out of scope without proper deallocation (call to `Dispose()`).

Comment: @VirtualVDX That website is talking about unmanaged resources, like database connections, in which case, it becomes paramount to dispose of that object or else you would potentially leak memory.  You don't have the same worries with a ToolStripMenuItem.  You can look at the source code [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx), search for ToolStripMenuItem, etc.